# Как выйти с учетной записи в Stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, интерфейс

Как выйти с учетной записи в Stackoverflow? Кэш что ли удалять?)))

Comment: В правом верхнем углу последняя иконка и ссылка "Выйти".

Comment: @entithat, иконки слева на право: Профиль, входящие, последние достижения, справка, список всех сайтов. И все, нет кнопки "Выйти"

Comment: Кнопка "Выйти" находиться в секции "Список всех сайтов". Попробуйте.